# Not able to read PDFs using tabula library in python

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, tabula-py

(My work is on PyCharm application in Windows)

Task is to write a python program for converting PDF file to Excel using the Tabula library. Starting program to read the pages of the PDF is below:

```
import tabula

data= tabula.read_pdf("EROLLGEN-S20-62-FinalRoll-Revision1-HIN-1-WI.pdf", pages="all")
print(data)
```

Getting following errors:

1.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rupesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py", line 88, in _run
    result = subprocess.run(
  File "C:\Users\Rupesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Rupesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Rupesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

2. 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rupesh/pythonProject/pdf2excel/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    data= tabula.read_pdf("EROLLGEN-S20-62-FinalRoll-Revision1-HIN-1-WI.pdf", pages="all")
  File "C:\Users\Rupesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py", line 425, in read_pdf
    output = _run(java_options, tabula_options, path, encoding)
  File "C:\Users\Rupesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py", line 99, in _run
    raise JavaNotFoundError(JAVA_NOT_FOUND_ERROR)
tabula.errors.JavaNotFoundError: `java` command is not found from this Python process.Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`
```

After some research, figured out that Java needs to be installed and path needs to be included in system environment variables for Tabula to work. Tried with different versions of Java - jre-1.8, jdk-1.8, jdk-20, verified that Java is properly installed.

C:\Users\Rupesh>java --version
java 20.0.2 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)

What should be done to get rid of these errors?